# The datepicker is hidden when table data is less inside tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-datepicker

There is a datepicker inside tabe. When I open datapicker it will work correctly when the table data is more but if I remove table data it hiding inside..adding both screen .(Angular project)

[Datepicker when table data is more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5e1L.png)
[Datepicker when table is less or not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLyWd.png)

I tried to add drop up using java script but it when I open drop it also hiding inside as I added screenshot. Also tried "datepicker-append-to-body".

Comment: maybe you can try to add z-index for the datepicker container